# Most common audio volume range mode

Tags: javascript, html, audio, volume

Setting the audio (media) element volume can be done with
`media.volume [ = value ]`
as stated [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-volume-dev), where value is a float/double value between 0 and 1. The page also states that "The range need not be linear.". I am trying to play sounds at specific relative values. I.e. play one sound at reference level and then another, say 3 dB lower.
The standard does not specify if the range is scaling the energy (square of waveform) or pressure (wave-form) (or something else), so I guess it's the latter (raw waveform). I.e.
To reduce by 3 dB I do the following:

```
let dL = -3;
media.volume *= 20 * Math.log10(10,dL/20);
```

I have tested with a professional sound pressure level meter (B&K 2250), reducing in steps from 0 dB to -78 dB, and only at the last step was there a bit background noise (electrical) from the soundcard (motherboard) that resulted in less reduction of the output level than expected. Otherwise the result was a perfectly linear shift in output level with the programmatically shift in level (`dL`). I have tested this with (Chrome/EDGE and Firefox, latest versions as of today 2021-09-02).

So - the standard is a bit vague but the way these three browsers interpret the mode/way of scaling sound level seems the most natural way. Does anyone know if any other browser interpret the volume attribute differently?

Here is my complete test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>Test audio level</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <audio id="music">
            <source src="94dB 1kHz.WAV" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>   
    </div>
    <button onclick="lowerAudio()">Lower</button>
    <button onclick="raiseAudio()">Raise</button>
    <button onclick="fadeAudio()">Fade out</button>
    
    <script>
    music = document.getElementById("music");
    music.controls = true;
    music.loop=true;
    music.load();

   
    var scaleDown = Math.pow(10,-3/20);
    var scaleUp = Math.pow(10,3/20);
    var fadeOutFactor = Math.pow(10,-0.5/20);

    function lowerAudio() {
        let v = music.volume * scaleDown;
        if (v > 0 )  {music.volume =v;}
        var dB = 20*Math.log10(music.volume);
        console.log("music is now at " + dB + " dB and volume is " + music.volume);
    }

    function raiseAudio() {
        let v = music.volume * scaleUp;
        if (v <= 1 )  {music.volume =v;}
        else {music.volume = 1;}
        var dB = 20*Math.log10(music.volume);
        console.log("music is now at " + dB + " dB and volume is " + music.volume);
    }

    
    function fadeAudio() {
        var fadeAudio = setInterval(function () {
            // check if higher than -100 dB
            if (music.volume > 1e-5) {
            music.volume *= scaleDown;
        }
        else
        {
            var dB = 20*Math.log10(music.volume);
            console.log("music is now at " + dB + " dB and volume is " + music.volume);
            clearInterval(fadeAudio);
        }
        }, 50);
    }


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just fyi - the ID `lower-music-button` is repeated 3 times - this **might** lead to unpredicted results. All ID attributes should be unique